# MAMP mysql not starting

Tags: mysql, mamp

> Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect
>   150629 15:44:35 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql
>   150629 15:44:35 [Warning] You have forced lower_case_table_names to 0 through a command-line option, even though your file system '/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/' is case insensitive.  This means that you can corrupt a MyISAM table by accessing it with different cases. You should consider changing lower_case_table_names to 1 or 2
>   150629 15:44:35 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>   150629 15:44:35 [Note] Plugin 'ndbcluster' is disabled.
>   /Applications/MAMP/Library/libexec/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
>   150629 15:44:35 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
>   150629 15:44:35  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 1 402900962
>   150629 15:44:35 [ERROR] /Applications/MAMP/Library/libexec/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/host.frm' (errno: 13)
>   150629 15:44:35 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: './mysql/host.frm' (errno: 13)
>   150629 15:44:35 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended

I can't find mysql.sock file anywhere. This is MAMP 1.9 on OS X version 10.8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to try is to change the ownership of the datadir of MySQL, for example, if you run MySQL with user mysql:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /path/to/datadir
```

check the privilges of /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/ directory for creating socket.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed the privileges had changed so I just reinstalled mamp.

Comment: I have also same problem, and i tried `chown -R mysql:mysql /path/to/datadir` buts its not working