# mysql not starting on mamp

Tags: mysql, apache, mamp

I've been using MAMP for quite a while now but a few months ago it started to give me issues. I've since looked online through google searches and stack overflow to find a resolution but I haven't seen anything that could help me yet.

I've searched for some articles but these that I felt would have been close to helping me did not:

[MAMP mysql not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116137/mamp-mysql-not-starting)
I'm not sure the path to my data directory? and anything I type in the terminal seems to come back as commmand not found

[Mysql service won't start, InnoDB init function error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22036724/mysql-service-wont-start-innodb-init-function-error)

[MAMP mysql server won't start. No mysql processes are running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021564/mamp-mysql-server-wont-start-no-mysql-processes-are-running)
I attempted to killall but "No matching processes belonging to you were found" error was shown

About an hour ago my mqsql was working but not apache, so I found as article that said to rename Library/bin/envvars to _envvars, apache worked on startup but then mysql didn't.

I'm not getting any errors in my php log but here is my apache and mysql logs.

Here is a snippet from the bottom of the mysql error log

```
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
170118 15:52:39  InnoDB: Unable to open the first data file
InnoDB: Error in opening ./ibdata1
170118 15:52:39  InnoDB: Operating system error number 35 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Error number 35 means 'Resource temporarily unavailable'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
170118 15:52:39 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
170118 15:52:39 InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
170118 15:52:39 InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
170118 15:52:39 InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
170118 15:52:39 InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
170118 15:52:39 InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
170118 15:52:39 InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
170118 15:52:39 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
170118 15:52:39 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
170118 15:52:39 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
170118 15:52:39 [ERROR] Aborting

170118 15:52:39 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

170118 15:52:39 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

and then the apache error log

```
[Wed Jan 18 15:48:28 2017] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jan 18 15:48:28 2017] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Jan 18 15:48:28 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8zh DAV/2 PHP/5.3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jan 18 15:48:31 2017] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Jan 18 15:51:01 2017] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jan 18 15:51:01 2017] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Jan 18 15:51:01 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8zh DAV/2 PHP/5.3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

My ports are: apache 80 and mysql 3306.

If anyone might know what might be happening that would be amazing..

Comment: [See this may solve your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33746682/2151290)

Comment: check your system other application my get mysql port

Answer (score 3):

Back in December, when I had this same problem in my Mac, I explored a bit and found a very simple solution:

1. Quit MAMP
2. In the finder go to Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56/ and delete the last log file, in my case ib_logfile1. (It might be a good idea to back up this file before deleting it, or alternatively move it to a different location instead of deleting it.)
3. Restart MAMP. That's it!

Some people had reported that deleting also ib_logfile0 was necessary, but not in my case. You can check this in [JuanFra.me](https://juanfra.me/2013/01/mysql-not-starting-mamp-fix/#comment-15365) blog where I first posted my solution last year.

I don't know why or how this solution worked, but it seems that it has been helpful to many others, as reported in JuanFra's blog. I hope it is useful to you as well.

Answer (score 0):

- Another copy of MySQL/MariaDB currently running?
- `ibdata1` on some odd file system partition?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would check if there was another copy running?

Answer (score 0):

Did you by chance restore from a backup taken from an instance that was up?

The following is excerpted from     https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-types.html

Physical backup methods have these characteristics: 
   • Backups can be performed while the MySQL server is not running. If the server is running, it is necessary to perform appropriate locking so that the server does not change database contents during the backup. MySQL Enterprise Backup does this locking automatically for tables that require it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sorry I didn't get to this sooner, had no idea I have comments on this as I was getting notifications. I didn't restore from a backup at all. One day it was working and then a few weeks later it wasn't. I have no idea what happened in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

To stop MySQL There are different cases depending on whether you installed MySQL with the official binary installer, using MacPorts, or using Homebrew:
MacPorts

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql.plist
```

Note: this is persistent after reboot.
Homebrew

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

Binary installer

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM stop
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM restart
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sorry I didn't get to this sooner, had no idea I have comments on this as I was getting notifications. Do I place this in my terminal window?

Comment: Yes, through these commands you will stop MySQL and restart it. As your problem caused by open threads these commands can help you to close theme

Answer (score 0):

If MySQL isn't starting it is pretty likely that it could already be running. You can very easily manually turn it off in the terminal.

I've had this happen to me a few times and I believe it has something to do with not shutting MAMP off correctly.

1. Quit MAMP.
2. Open the terminal and type: `killall -9 mysqld`
3. Restart MAMP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sorry I didn't get to this sooner, had no idea I have comments on this as I was getting notifications. I do that and the terminal says "No matching processes belonging to you were found". This is assuming I just go to my Utilities > Terminal program to type this in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Quit MAMP
2. go to /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/ and add file
3. Restart MAMP. That's it!